# iPython/Jupyter notebooks following deprecation of GoogleDrive "host"

Tags: google-drive-api, jupyter-notebook

For several years, I've been storing iPython/Jupyter notebooks in public folders on my GoogleDrive and then copying a path like this

```
https://www.googledrive.com/host/folder_id/file_name.ipynb
```

into the [Jupyter nbViewer](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/). This gives me a link to my notebook that I can share with colleagues.

A few days ago all my links stopped working, and after a bit of searching it seems as though Google have [discontinued the hosting feature](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en).

I don't want to host a website from my GoogleDrive, but I do need to be able to share iPython notebooks via nbViewer. **Are there any alternative ways to continue to do this via my GoogleDrive account, or do I need to look into moving my files elsewhere?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Github support ipyton notebook format. So you can upload your file there.

For example, like this [file](https://github.com/danielfrg/pelican-ipynb/blob/master/tests/pelican/content/with-liquid-tag.ipynb).
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Aaron. Yes, that's a possibility, although I think GitHub might be over-the-top for most of what I do. I work on lots of different projects and many of them involve only small amounts of code. I usually create one folder per project on GoogleDrive, then make a public sub-folder which I use to store and share my notebooks. I've used GitHub in the past for more complicated things, but I don't know whether it's possible to e.g. have public versus private parts of a single repository? Do you think GitHub is a reasonable alternative to Drive for "everyday" file storage and document sharing?

Comment: Github provides education account  https://education.github.com/  , you can have private repos there.

Comment: Hi @Aaron. Thanks again for your reply. My organisation has a "paid-for" GitHub account, so I can create private repos. However, for most of my notebooks I don't need version control, and the nice thing about Drive is (was) that I could have all my data and a few notebooks in the same parent folder, with different permissions for the sub-folders. My datasets are often 100s of GB in size, which [I don't think GitHub is designed for](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/). I could put my notebooks on GitHub and my data on Drive, but I'd prefer to keep them together if possible.

Comment: Hi, @JamesS. I think your datasets are too large, I don't know other solution that fit your need.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help :-)